# Example - regression testing

Tags: testing, regression

There remain two questions:

1. When I add or modify a module in the implementation of a use case it is necessary to repeat the tests to verify that other use cases have not been influenced by the modification.
2. This test is called regression testing.

Do you think that this is Right?

Comment: [Regression testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_testing).

Comment: When we made modifications to base classes high up the inheritance hierarchy, or in classes that were widely used in composition or object factories, we would run just such "regression tests" and they needed to be more thorough as the potential impact might be more widely distributed. Quite the time-consuming pain, but on occasion it really, really saved us from putting potentially disastrous changes into production.

Answer (score 0):

You may be right on your understanding. Regression testing is an activity performed to ensure the different functionalities of the system are still working as expected and the new functionalities added did not break any of the existing ones.

Secondly, you generally write automated tests or do manual testing to the above mentioned testing. It could be a combination of API/UI/Unit tests run periodically. Regression testing can be performed in various phases of the SDLC, it all depends on the context.